# Monotone functions satisfy autonomous ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a follow-up to [What smooth functions are solutions of an autonomous ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863392/what-smooth-functions-are-solutions-of-an-autonomous-ode).

Given a function $y : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \in C^1$ does there exist a continuous function $f : \operatorname{Im} y\to \mathbb R$ with $\dot y = f(y)$?.

If $f$ is *strictly* monotone, then the answer is 'yes' since $y$ is invertible and so we can take $f := \dot y \circ y^{-1}$.

What I don't understand is why this is true if we remove the "strictly" part as implicitly  mentioned in the question linked (supposedly it's easy to see). It's clear that there are non-strictly monotone functions that satisfy this: just consider any constant function $y$ and take $f = 0$.

How can I prove the existence of $f$ for monotone $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say $y$ is nondecreasing, for definiteness. Then $y(t_1) \le y(t_2)$ whenever $t_1 < t_2$, and if $y(t_1)=y(t_2)$, then $y(t)$ must take that value in the whole interval $[t_1,t_2]$, in which case $\dot y(t)=0$ on $[t_1,t_2]$ (including the endpoints, since $y$ was assumed to be differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$). So for any value $C$ which is taken only once, say $y(t_0)=C$, we let $f(C)=\dot y(t_0)$, and for any value $C$ which is taken on a proper interval, we let $f(C)=0$. Since $\dot{y}$ is continuous by assumption,
so is $f$. (For example, $f$ takes values close to zero when $t$ is close to an interval where $y$ is constant, so $f$ is continuous at $C=0$.)